# PS+ account belgium/france

Tags: ps4

I resently bought a ps4 in France and would like to start using ps4+, but i live in Belgium. Though I have plans to move over to France in about 1 year. I already made my ps4 with country France, and I was wondering if I could buy PS4+ through a belgian creditcard for my French PS4+ account.

90% of the time i'll be playing in Belgium for the next year, and be able to have the French released games? Or doesn't it work like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, EU has 1 Playstation store (except for UK and Germany). So you can buy from there in any EU country (again except for Germany and UK).

Also you don't have to be worried about region locked games, only the stores are region locked. But if you have several accounts (1 for each store) you can just buy from that store and download it to your PS4 and play with any account.